# Way to tune model hyperparameters for multivariate (multi outcome) regression with tidymodels?

Tags: r, tidymodels, mlp, nnet

I am using an mlp with tidymodels, I have ~20 outcomes and ~65 predictors. I get the following error when trying to use the tune package
A | error:   Internal error: Multiple outcomes are not supported in `.estimate_metrics()`.

Does anyone know a way to tune parameters for such a scenario?

If there is not a way to use a pre built package to do this, can someone offer advice on how to use tidymodels to set up a 'manual' cross validation for neural network hyperparameters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.